# How to setup oversized physical screen resolution in winxp

Tags: windows, resolution

My physical resolution is 1024x768, but I need to virtually set up resolution in Windows XP to be 1280x1024 and use it by scrolling on the edges of my desktop.

The reason is that I have special software which only works in 1280x1024 resolution.

Maybe this feature is already included out of the box? If not, I need a simple (tiny, fast) software, maybe a driver for a virtual display with the desired resolution.

Please don't suggest [SDesk](http://www.tomasek.cz/stary_soft/sdesk/index.html). It is very old (2002) software and not really compatible with XP SP3. Also, any virtual desktop manager is not suitable for my task, because I only need to set virtual resolution and scrolling on *one* desktop.

Comment: Firstly, please don't edit out the duplicate links. Secondly, please don't double post. If your [previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/322997/how-to-setup-oversized-physical-screen-resolution-in-winxp) was closed, add some additional information and notify a moderator to have it reopened.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup oversized physical screen resolution in Windows XP?](http://superuser.com/questions/322997/how-to-setup-oversized-physical-screen-resolution-in-windows-xp)

Comment: Do you have an ATI graphics card? If so, that functionality is available from the graphic driver control panel, at on some versions I used. So, take a look there.

Comment: I need universal solution, not only for ATI.